# Как правильно использовать composer?

Tags: php, composer

Как правильно использовать composer?

Я установил согласно официальной инструкции, проверил  `composer -v` всё работает. После чего, перешел в папку с проектом, открыл от туда консоль, и установил conposer.json, командой `composer init`.

Но когда я пытаюсь выполнить эту команду:
`php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet`
то, происходит ошибка:
`Could not open input file: ~/composer.phar`

Она говорит о том, что не находит `composer.phar`, который лежит там, куда мы устанавливали composer. 
Я конечно понимаю, что можно сделать так:

```
php e:\Developers\WebDeveloper\OpenServer-WebProg\modules\php\PHP-5.6\composer.phar  require cboden/ratchet
```

Но все-таки, почему не работает так, как сделать чтобы работало?:

```
php ~/composer.phar require cboden/ratchet
```

Comment: ~ - это ссылка на домашнюю папку в Linux, если у Вас не linux, то система не понимает, какой файл вы хотите запустить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы установили композер глобально, то нужно его использовать так

```
composer require cboden/ratchet
```