# Установка Ratchet

Tags: php, composer

Здравствуйте. Устанавливаю библиотеку Ratchet при помощи composer. Скачал composer, создал json файл с необходимым кодом:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
    }
}
```

в консолe прописываю

> D:\OpenServer\domains\m>php composer.phar install

но php не является внутренней или внешней командой. Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Укажите полный путь к php, напрмер D:\OpenServer\domains\m>c:\php\php.exe composer.phar install

Comment: у OpenServer уже прописано окружение и более того, там уже есть композер.... достаточно писать composer.phar install и кажется даже просто composer бла бла бла......... только надо в папку своего проекта предварительно войти

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511817/191482